# Access Hidden Field Values

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to access the hidden field values in classic ASP , but not able to access...Could you please help me out with this..I am kinda stuck here trying to access the values....

```
    *<input type="hidden" id="totalrecords" name="totalrecords" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" id="totalrecords" name="totalrecords" value="2">
   <input type="hidden" id="totalrecords" name="totalrecords" value="3">
   <input type="hidden" id="totalrecords" name="totalrecords" value="4">
   <input type="hidden" id="totalrecords" name="totalrecords" value="5">
   <%
    'trying to access it here
    totalParts=totalrecords(0).value
    %>*
```

Answer (score 1):

in asp when Name of element is same then when we do request.form("totalrecords") you will get value in comma saperated. like 1,2,3,4,5 so you can split and get value.

```vb
dim arr : arr = split(request.form("totalrecords"),", ")

for i=0 to ubound(arr)

response.write(arr(i)) 

next
```